# Leave directories in dos/cmd

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, ms-dos

I enter CMD or DOS prompt, (doesn't matter) and I enter "cd desktop/" so now I am in C:\users\USER\desktop\ and now I want to leave the desktop\ directory, how, because doing "cd USER" obviously does not work, because it is looking for the directory USER in the desktop.

so I just want to know, how do I leave directories in DOS/cmd?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy

`cd ..`
backs up one directory level.

Any folder

==============

**Followup:**  as others have noted, there are various ways to construct commands. That is part of the flexibility.

Another thing (XP forward to 11) is that Up Arrow and Down Arrow also list backward and forward through commands to recall them. A neat feature to work with commands.

Comment: CD space ..   So yes a space between CD and ..

Comment: thanks, i've accepted your answer, there is just something fun about opening files and creating folders with CMD. plus, it makes you look smart

Comment: i have confirmed, it works with and without the space

Comment: I'd found refs quoting both ways, with & without space. I tested here on a nix terminal [don't have dos to hand] & it didn't like no space.

Comment: The non-space variant is a DOS-time (1980's) idiosyncrasy

Comment: with or without space!  `cd..` same result for `cd ..`, `cd../` or `
cd..\\`

Answer (score 2):

`cd ..` takes you to the parent directory.
`cd \` takes you back to the root, ie `C:\>` prompt.

Comment: im gonna try confirm if these commands work in dos, they probably do considering the commands are very similar, plus, these are generic commands o change and create directories.

Comment: `C:\> cd /?` will print a short text that will help you, as will "all" (i.e. most) commands, some are re-compiled-for-windows versions of Linux commands; those most often take either `-h` or `--help` as argument to do the same.